# 100% True Black problem in Illustrator

Tags: print-design

In an Illustrator file, Even though I used the default black(100% K), my printer said the pdf is not 100% black. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: I more or less have the same problem. I don't think I messed up with CMYK/RGB setting. There is got to be some reason...

Comment: Did you start with an RGB document then *switch* to CMYK??

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with Embed: ICC Profile

Comment: @Scott you mean me? no...

Comment: I wasn't specifically addressing you @TroyWoo However, "no" is not a valid answer to my question. You **must** start with one or the other.

Comment: Check your opacity setting. Could have accidentally bumped it down.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Preferences > Appearance of Black and make sure you change your output settings to output all blacks accurately.

[image: blacks]

Comment: Why things are not set this way by default boggles my mind. Adobe *wants* your output color to be inaccurate.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on where your output it going, you may also need to bump the CMY to 100% as well as the K

Comment: 100C/100M/100Y/100K = 400% ink coverage. Never heard of any printer allowing anything above 320% and most often 300% is the maximum.

Comment: Doing that was the only way to get a real black fabric from Spoonflower. Anything less produced a dark gray. I don't remember if the other printers I've used have complained to me about black.

Comment: Never heard of Spoonflower before. Be wary though.. an online print-on-demand, send-us-any-old-jpg-and-we-print-it, often has very rudimentary specifications. For commercial printing you **never** want 100% for all colors. It's unlikely this question is referring to colors for Spoonflower.

Comment: http://www.spoonflower.com they do custom fabric printing for the craft community.

Comment: Their FAQ includes this instruction: "With the water-based inks we use, you can achieve millions of beautiful colors. Because of our digital process, there are no caps on how many colors you can use. For the best results, and to be able to use the Spoonflower Color Guide and Spoonflower Color Map, please use the RGB color space from the beginning of the design process to the end." They would want an RGB(0,0,0) black rather than anything in CMYK.